# how to write the method declaration java

Tags: java, methods, get, declaration

trying to figure out how I am going to build the method declaration for this method.

```
double cost = School.getCost(782.42, new Student(int credits));
```

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
public void getCost(double in_cost, //not sure what to do here?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Assigning void to double,and your final method looks like

```
public static double getCost(double in_cost, Student student)
{
 double result;
  int student_credits=student.credits;

  // calculations

  return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
public static void getCost(double in_cost, Student student)
```

It is static because you are invoking that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
public static void getCost(double in_cost, Student student)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning the return value of the method to a `double` which means the return value of the method must be `double`:

```
public static double getCost
```

Now let's look at the parameter list, the method requires a floating point number and a `Student` object. We can deduce that the second parameter must be a `Student`. So what about the first? Is it a `float` `double`? Since it doesn't have any suffixes such as `F` or `f`, it is a `double`:

```
public static double getCost (double d, Student s) {

}
```

The parameters in the above code are arbitary, you can give more meaningful names to them if you want.